# Magento (2.0.5) review rest api

Tags: review, magento-2.0.5

I want to get reviews of the products using magento 2.0.5 . I think rest api for it is not being implemented.

**Can u give me some idea about how to start?**

And I have tried tutorial from Alan Kent blog(https://alankent.me/2015/07/24/creating-a-new-rest-web-service-in-magento-2/). But it is showing the following error.

[2016-06-09 08:49:34] main.CRITICAL: exception 'ReflectionException' with message 'Report ID: webapi-57592d9ec153f; Message: Class Magento\Review\Api\Review does not exist' in C:\xampp\htdocs\magento\vendor\magento\framework\Webapi\ErrorProcessor.php:194
Stack trace:

0 C:\xampp\htdocs\magento\vendor\magento\framework\Webapi\ErrorProcessor.php(139): Magento\Framework\Webapi\ErrorProcessor->_critical(Object(ReflectionException))

1 C:\xampp\htdocs\magento\vendor\magento\module-webapi\Controller\Rest.php(163): Magento\Framework\Webapi\ErrorProcessor->maskException(Object(ReflectionException))

2 C:\xampp\htdocs\magento\var\generation\Magento\Webapi\Controller\Rest\Interceptor.php(24): Magento\Webapi\Controller\Rest->dispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))

3 C:\xampp\htdocs\magento\vendor\magento\framework\App\Http.php(115): Magento\Webapi\Controller\Rest\Interceptor->dispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))

4 C:\xampp\htdocs\magento\vendor\magento\framework\App\Bootstrap.php(258): Magento\Framework\App\Http->launch()

5 C:\xampp\htdocs\magento\index.php(39): Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap->run(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Http))

6 {main} [] []

Answer (score 1):

We have implemented the code for the rest api for review and added into the github. here is the github link you can check the code having comment "Added Review APi":

https://github.com/ajay-ipragmatech/magento2

Or you can download our free plugin from the following links 
Review/Rating API Plugin : http://www.ipragmatech.com/products/review-rest-api-magento/

Comment: @user40382, This Module producing an error in magento 2.2

Answer (score 0):

According to [this](https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/2495) issue on github, rest API for reviews are not available yet

You can try to follow this [tutorial](https://alankent.me/2015/07/24/creating-a-new-rest-web-service-in-magento-2/) from Alan Kent blog if you want to create your own rest web service